# Grep pattern in ksh

Tags: grep, ksh

a small question regarding grep.

I'm doing :

```
find . -type d
```

And I have three directories :

```
./backup-2013-11-27
./backup-2013-11-26
./backup-2013-11-28
```

If I only want to retrieve the one from 11/26, I do :

```
find . -type d | grep "2013.*11.*26"
```

and it works.

However, I can't understand why :

```
find . -type d | grep "2013*11*26"
```

doesn't work ...
Indeed, I'm not using regexp here, I'm using pattern, so `*` should be used as wild card, or not?

Comment: Quoted wildcard patterns are [not expanded](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11456496/2105514). You should also note that [wild card patterns are not regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1324425/2105514)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` uses a different regular expression matching than the korn shell.

That is why it is necessary for grep to include the `.*` (match any character 0 or more times). In `ksh` (and in `bash`) you use just `*` for that pattern.

The `grep` way is often called regex pattern and `ksh` wildcard pattern.